# Why this is a valid JavaScript function definition? So odd (but it surely fails to run)

Tags: javascript

I have just found that I can **define** a function in JavaScript like this:

```
function a(){ ([]())   }
```

and similarly, this way is also a valid **function definition**.

```
function a(){ ([]())()()([])([])   }
```

It doesn't even look like a valid syntax, doesn't it? But the compiler doesn't blame when define them. (Surely invoking a() will cause you an error later)

A function of an empty array? A function of a function of an empty array, or something? I can't even understand how this is considered valid to be defined as a function in JavaScript compiler.

***In case you're curious***: Not all these kind of function definitions will pass the compiler. You may try defining this below.

```
function a(){ ([]())()()([])([]){}   }
```

JS compiler won't let you define it.

**I know the function will not be able to invoke, but to my wondering, I can define it**. So I'm eager to know why this is valid to define.

Comment: TypeError: [] is not a function

Comment: For the people who downvoted, please leave your comments why you think it's worth downvote without explanation.

Comment: After reading some more, you're basically executing an array (first example) in parenthesis, then trying to execute it again. Meh.

Comment: I'm looking for an explanation on "why this is not failing the compiler?" What makes it valid and compilable.

Comment: Any PrimaryExpression can be the callee of a CallExpression, including an array initializer. see http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2. If you wonder why things like this work as they do, I recommend to have a look at the spec.

Comment: @FelixKling Based on  this, when the compiler won't blame at this even the function definition looks difficult to explain and tokenize, I think I could anticipate some typo error which may happen.

Comment: @TaoP.R.: That's why we have linters.

Comment: @TaoP.R. That is a problem with most weakly-typed language

Answer (score 5):

`[]` creates an empty array.  It's not a function, so treating it as a function by calling it like `[]()` will give a runtime error, but there's nothing syntactically invalid about it.

And wrapping stuff in parentheses, `[]` vs. `([])`, has no effect when used on its own like that, but again it's valid syntax.

Comment: Look closely. In the second function the `([])` is actually a function call

Comment: Hmm, `([])([])` makes less sense when it follows a non function though, in terms of syntax.

Comment: Isn't in this case, `([])` wrapping an array in a private scope?

Comment: I found that I can put `()()()`, nesting it as many times as I want also. The spec allows it.

Comment: @taxicala: `(...)` does not create scope.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `a()`, you will get a runtime error.

The thing is, when you define a function (like what you did), the function obviously won't be executed so any runtime error will not be reported (since the engine has no way of knowing a runtime error except by actually running the function).

---

EDIT:
In response to the author's comment, imagine this function:

```
function a(){ (alert()) }
```

which is syntactically similar to the first function. However this function is perfectly fine - no runtime errors.

That's why the engine allows you to define functions like this. In order for the engine to catch the problem in `function a(){ ([]()) }`, it has to make the inference "`[]` is an array, which is not callable, so this function generates an error". However, calling an uncallable object is a runtime error (TypeError) so the engine will not make the said inference - as that would be trying to catch a runtime error at compile-time.

P.S.: Calling an uncallable object is not necessarily a runtime error in other languages. In most strictly-typed language that is a compile-time error. If you do in Java `int[] x; x();`, that would generate a compile-time error.

---

As to the second function, you need to understand the concept of higher-order functions. If you don't know what that is, I will do a simple explanation here.

Imagine this:

```
function addone(x){return x+1;}
function f(){return addone;}
```

now if you run `f()(1)`, that is equivalent to `addone(1)`, which is `2`.

Now `f` is a second-order function, you can define a third-order function:

```
function g(){return f;}
```

Then `g()()(1)` is again `2`. If you want, you can define a hundredth-order function. Though in real code you rarely need more than second-order.

Now back to the second function in the OP:

```
function a(){ ([]())()()([])([])   }
```

You are trying to run `[]` as a fifth-order function, which is syntactically perfectly fine. Again, checking whether `[]` is actually a fifth-order function is a runtime thing.

Comment: Actually I made it an ambiguous question. I did want to say "why the compiler allows us to define the function with these statements". Surely it won't run but the compiler doesn't complain anything when defining it.

Answer (score 0):

Please note down. 
1) A JavaScript function returns undefined (if there is no return statement define) even if there is nothing inside function.
2) Similiary ()()()([])([]) is valid. Because there is no any syntax error. Code inside functions are validated for syntax error inside validator e.g. there should be no code after () except semicolor ; or () etc.  All type error will be validated only at execution.

3) This is valid but when you call this function, It will throw uncaught typerror

Comment: I made it unclear at the first place though. Seems like people think I mean it is invokable. Nope, I meant "able to define it".